# Finding a basis for any given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am wondering what the process is for finding a basis given any kind of subspace. In this example, I can picture just matrices with a 1 only in c, only in d, only in a, and only in a+b but I feel this is not very rigorous and with more difficult examples it will be very difficult to do the same.

What is a more step-by-step approach to doing this? Is there some way to set up a matrix that will do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I suspect looking at a "basis" in the variables (ie letting each variable be 1, with all the others zero) will lead to a basis in the matrix space.

Comment: At the very least, this will give you a spanning set.

Comment: So am I right if I found that the dimensions of both W_1 and W_2 are 4 and that the intersection is 1 (the matrix with 1 in a_13 and 0 everywhere else). I followed what you suggested.

Comment: What about the matrix with ones in the first two positions in the bottom row?  (That is to say: you still have to consider linear combinations.)

Comment: Oh ok, I had noticed that but thought they had to be the same matrices to be considered the intersection. So then is the intersection: the one I first mentionned and the one with ones in the first two positions of the bottom row or the first one and the one with the ones in first two positions of bottom row plus the ones that can be combined to make it?